# Let $ c \in R $ define $ f:(0,\infty) \to R^+.$ Show that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = \infty \iff \lim_{x \to c} 1/f(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Let $ c \in R \; define \; f:(0,\infty) \to R^+.$ Show that $\lim_{x
> > \to c} f(x) = \infty \iff \lim_{x \to c} 1/f(x) = 0$

Case 1

Let $ \lim_{x \to c}f(x)= \infty$

$\forall \alpha  > 0 \; \exists \; \delta >0 \; \; such \; \; that $

$x \in (c, \infty) \; \; 0<x-c<\delta \Rightarrow f(x) > \alpha$

Let $\epsilon > 0 \; taking \; \alpha = 1/\epsilon$

$x \in (c, \infty) \; 0<x-c<\delta \Rightarrow f(x) > 1/\epsilon \Rightarrow 0<f(x)<\epsilon \Rightarrow |1/f(x)|<\epsilon$

or, $\lim_{x \to c}1/f(x) = 0$

Case 2 : Let $ \lim_{x \to c}1/f(x)=0$

$x \in (c, \infty) 0<x-c<\delta \Rightarrow |1/f(x)|< \epsilon$

Let $\alpha >0 \; \; taking \; \;  epsilon = 1/\alpha$

$x \in (c, \infty) 0<x-c<\delta \Rightarrow |1/f(x)|< 1/\alpha \Rightarrow 1/f(x) < 1/alpha \Rightarrow f(x) > \alpha$

$f(x) \to \infty \; as \; x \to c$

Is my proof correct?

Is there a shorter way of doing it using sequential criterion ?

Answer (score 0):

Your proof looks fine, but you can make your proof easier to read with something like this:

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. If $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to c$, then there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $c$ such that whenever $x\in N$, we have $f(x) > 1/\epsilon$. Hence whenever $x\in N$ we also have $1/f(x) < \epsilon$. The converse is similar.